# How to separate the matched output for every search block

Tags: linux, awk, grep

How to separate the matched output for every search block

```
$ az resource list -ojson |egrep  "changedTime|createdTime|resourceGroup|Environment|name"
   "changedTime": "2020-09-15T08:26:43.838097+00:00",
    "createdTime": "2020-09-15T08:16:43.311725+00:00",
    "name": "AzureBackup_1",
    "resourceGroup": "AzureBackupRG_westus2_1",
    "changedTime": "2020-09-16T17:54:18.501492+00:00",
    "createdTime": "2020-09-16T17:44:18.069150+00:00",
    "name": "AzureBackup_2",
    "resourceGroup": "AzureBackupRG_westus2_1",
```

## What tried:

```
$ az resource list -ojson |egrep  "changedTime|createdTime|resourceGroup|Environment|name" --group-separator="SEP"
```

But above is not working...

## Desired:

```
   "changedTime": "2020-09-15T08:26:43.838097+00:00",
    "createdTime": "2020-09-15T08:16:43.311725+00:00",
    "name": "AzureBackup_1",
    "resourceGroup": "AzureBackupRG_westus2_1",

    "changedTime": "2020-09-16T17:54:18.501492+00:00",
    "createdTime": "2020-09-16T17:44:18.069150+00:00",
    "name": "AzureBackup_2",
    "resourceGroup": "AzureBackupRG_westus2_1",
```

Comment: Since you are consuming JSON, you should consider using a tool that speaks JSON, for instance `jq`

Comment: what we don't see is the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
az resource list -ojson | egrep  "changedTime|createdTime|resourceGroup|Environment|name|^  \}," | awk '/  \}/{$0=""} 1'
```

`^  \},` on the egrep line mark the end of block.

awk command then replace that line with an empty string.

Comment: This works nicely, can you explain the awk work here please.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
az resource list -ojson | awk '/changedTime|createdTime|Environment|name/ { print $0 } /resourceGroup/ { print $0"\n" }'
```

Take the output of the Azure CLI command and pipe it through awk, removing the need for egrep. When the text "resourceGroup" is found, print the line ($0) followed by the new line, otherwise we just print the line as is for the tags required e.g changedTime, createdTime, Environment and name.

Comment: `/a/ || /b/` = `/a|b/`. Also, `$0=$0` (and so that whole `/foo/ || /bar/... {$0=$0}` statement) does absolutely nothing in this case.

Comment: I've amended and have also realised that 1 will print all the lines from the az command and so have removed this.